# Generate alphanumeric ID from column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook containing a macro. The workbook contains a single worksheet where each row contains information on a particular asset; each row begins with an asset id. The asset id is composed of the letter "A" followed by followed by five numbers. Whenever a new asset is added to the worksheet, a unique asset ID should be included in the new row of data. For example, the last row has an asset ID of "A0006 ". I need a function written in vb that when called will read the last value in the asset id column (Column "A"), increment that value by one, and return the alphanumeric string. If the function were called now, it should return a value of "A0007".

Comment: why a vba function? A formula will work just as easily as well. `=Right(A5,1)+1` to increment last digit by 1 then you can concatenate that to a string. Otherwise, if you really need 'vba' please post your coding efforts and where you are stuck [see How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far so that we can help you. The purpose of StackOverflow is to help if you're struggling, but no one will do the work for you.

Comment: I have a userform attached to a worikbook. New asset information is added to the worksheet via a macro written in vb. Over time, the worksheet will have hundreds of rows of data. Column "A" contains the asset IDs. Using VB, I need to determine the last value at the bottom of column A, increment it by one, and return that value.

Comment: Function GenerateAssetID() As String
return .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
End Function

Comment: If you mean these ID's to be relevant long-term then generating each new one based off the "last" one in the list is not a good approach.  Use (eg) a named range to store the sequence number, and increment that each time you create a new ID.  As soon as you need to move items, delete items, or resort your data you'll find that approach has lots of advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub New_ID()

    Dim rLastValue As Range
    Dim alpha As String
    Dim numeric As Long

    Set rLastValue = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    alpha = Left(rLastValue, 1)
    numeric = Val(Replace(rLastValue, alpha, "")) + 1

    rLastValue.Offset(1) = alpha & Format(numeric, "0000")

End Sub
```